# Android - how to read file from /data/data/* without root permissions?

Tags: android, settings, root

For example, app "My backup pro" can do it without root, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your own files in `/data/data/` without root. Nobody, including My Backup Pro, can access arbitrary files in `/data/data/`. My Backup Pro does not claim to access files in `/data/data/`.